# How to pass list value to SQL query in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Hello I am beginner in python and I am using `sqlite3` as a database.

Problem: I want to insert/update data but I am not sure how do I pass list value in SQL query.

Here is an example of my list values:

```
['ABC', '60', '13999', [...]]
['BCD', '35', '124799', [...]]
['EFG', '699', '4799', [...]]
['PQR', '71', '139799', [...]]
```

I have `list[0]` as column name in database and `list[1]` is values of column.

I want to perform something like

```
Insert Into table(list[0]) Values(list[1])
```

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

If you're a beginner, I recommend you to use an ORM like [peewee](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it's well documented and much easier than make queries directly to the database.

But if you prefer to directly work with sqlite3, here you have an example:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('your_db_name.db')
c = conn.cursor()
# create table:
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE _TABLE-NAME_(
         column_1 datatype, 
         column_2 datatype,
         [...]
         column_n datatype)''')
# Insert a row using list elements:
c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s,%s,%s)" % (list[0], (list[1], (list[2], (list[3],))
# Commit changes:
conn.commit()
# Close connection:
conn.close()
```

Comment: I don't want to use peewee. Same thing i can perform using sqlite.